# LIKE match string ending with a number

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I've got a column that has resource paths in it that look like this:

```
/apiv3/widgets/100
/apiv3/widgets/search
/apiv3/widgets/new
```

I'm trying to get a LIKE or REG_EX like that will only match a string that ends in a number

I've tried a few things such as:

```
LIKE '\/apiv3\/widgets\/[0-9]%'
LIKE '\/apiv3\/widgets\/[^0-9]%'
```

How can I match a path that only ends in a numeric value of any arbitrary length?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a **regular expression with the `~` operator**.
For strings ending with a digit:

```
... WHERE value ~ '\d$'
```

`\d` ... [shorthand class for digits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE)
`$` ... matches at the [end of a string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE)

`E'\d$'` would be incorrect. This is *not* an [escape string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).

For strings ending with *only* digits after the last `/`:

```
... WHERE value ~ '/\d+$'
```

`+` ... one or more atoms
`/` ... literal '/'

Quick test:

```sql
SELECT x, x ~ '\d$' AS one,  x ~ '/\d+$' AS two
FROM  (
    VALUES
     ('/apiv3/widgets/100')
    ,('/apiv3/widgets/search')
    ,('/apiv3/widgets/new')
    ,('/apiv3/widgets/added_test17')
    ) AS t(x);
```

```
              x              | one | two
-----------------------------+-----+-----
 /apiv3/widgets/100          | t   | t
 /apiv3/widgets/search       | f   | f
 /apiv3/widgets/new          | f   | f
 /apiv3/widgets/added_test17 | t   | f
```

Answer (score 0):

See section 9.7.2 for 'SIMILAR' regular expressions. `LIKE` does not support them.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Examples:

```
'abc' SIMILAR TO 'abc'      true
'abc' SIMILAR TO 'a'        false
'abc' SIMILAR TO '%(b|d)%'  true
'abc' SIMILAR TO '(b|c)%'   false
```

Comment: [*Never* use `SIMILAR TO`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696).

Comment: Dude's trying to regex the contents of his database, I took it as a foregone conclusion that sense and sensibility had long since been defenestrated.